# Send function id of field form

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I have this script for see preview of pic until upload**

```
<script>

function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function (e) 
{
jQuery('#upfield_0')
.attr('src', e.target.result)
.width(150)
.height(150);
};

reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}

</script>
```

**HTML code it´s this :**

```
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img id="upfield_0" src="#" alt="your image" />
```

This works perfectly buy i need don´t use **readURL(this)** , i need send the script id of input file for works , and i don´t know how i must do this

**Here in the code from script , you can se this :**

**if (input.files && input.files[0])**

I need change this for id of input file , for send id and works , and don´t use "**this** inside function" , it´s possible do this and how , because i don´t know how change in the function this

**I want something as this :**

```
 <input type='file' onchange="readURL('ID Inside here');" />
```

**Thank´s for the help , regards**

Comment: what id you need to pass inside readURL method, what is script id? pls elaborate

Comment: Use `URL.createObjectURL` instead it's [faster](https://jsfiddle.net/fdzmd4mg/2/) and saves more cpu/memory